# How to ensure that an action only triggers when an action button is pressed with Shiny

Tags: r, shiny

I am trying to build a shiny app that, gets some twitter information.
I only want to run the function that makes the twitter API call when an action button is pressed.
 I have set up an action button, and attached it to an isolate function, however when I open the app it instantly tries to get the twitter data.

The logic is,

1. open app
2. enter search term in textInput box
3. Click action button
4. server code is executed, and a df is returned with my twitter information

```
library(shiny)
ui <- fluidPage(

  # Application title
  #titlePanel("Twitter Analytics"),

  fluidRow( 
    column( 4, titlePanel("Twitter Analytics")),
    column( 3),#, textOutput("mysearch") ),
    column( 4, textInput("searchstring", 
                      label = "",
                      value = "")),
    column(1, 
           br(),
           actionButton("action", "go"))

  )
)

server <- function(input, output) {

  output$mysearch  <- renderText({

    input$action

    df <- isolate(search_tweets( input$searchstring , n = 500, include_rts = FALSE))
  }) 
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

How can I ensure that this event only occurs when this button is clicked

Comment: does the answer work for you?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `eventReactive()` for that.

```
  twitter <- eventReactive(input$action,{
    search_tweets(input$searchstring)
  })

  output$mysearch  <- renderText({
    twitter()
  })
```

As i didnt have your twitter function, i simulated one:

```
search_tweets <- function(search) return(search)
```

**Full reproducible example:**

```
search_tweets <- function(search) return(search)

library(shiny)
ui <- fluidPage(

  # Application title
  #titlePanel("Twitter Analytics"),

  fluidRow( 
    column( 4, titlePanel("Twitter Analytics")),
    column( 3, textOutput("mysearch") ),
    column( 4, textInput("searchstring", 
                         label = "",
                         value = "")),
    column(1, 
           br(),
           actionButton("action", "go"))

  )
)

server <- function(input, output) {

  twitter <- eventReactive(input$action,{
    search_tweets(input$searchstring)
  })

  output$mysearch  <- renderText({
    twitter()
  }) 
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```